# How do I send a hexadecimal code

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to send a command line through PowerShell so I can power on a projector via serial port. I'm using a NEC projector and the command for turn on and turn off the projector are these:

Power On: `02H 00H 00H 00H 00H 02H`
Power Off: `02H 01H 00H 00H 00H 03H`

I use the manufacture's software and I did monitor what it sent and for turn it on it use the following:

Open COM port

wrote:

```
00 bf 00 00 01 00 c0
```

read:

```
20 bf 01 20 10 00 ff 22 4d 33 35 33 57 53 00 00
00 08 12 00 00 dd
```

wrote:

```
00 bf 00 00 01 02 c2
```

read:

```
20 bf 01 20 10 02 0f ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 1d
```

Wrote (this is the command line I identified in the manual):

```
02 00 00 00 00 02
```

and then it close the open COM port.

I'm trying to figure out how to send the command.
I did some digging and found out the command:

```
$port.WriteLine
```

but it doesn't send hex, it sends this:

```
30 30 20 62 66 20 30 30 20 30 30 20 30 31 20 30   00 bf 00 00 01 0 
30 20 63 30 0a                                    0 c0.
```

Comment: Can you please post the lines of code you use for sending?  It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do or how it's going wrong.

Comment: It may help to note that hexadecimal literals in PowerShell are written like `0x20 0xbf 0x01 etc...`

Comment: thanks all for helping, and I probably didn't give much information, what I post were the dump view of a software called serial port monitor, and what I was trying to do was sending the command codes through powershell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[Byte[]] $powerOn = 0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02
[Byte[]] $powerOff = 0x02,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03

# Use your COM port here
$port = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM3,9600,None,8,one
$port.Open()
$port.Write($powerOn, 0, $powerOn.Count)
# ...
$port.Write($powerOff, 0, $powerOff.Count)
$port.Close()
```

Comment: that work perfectly, thank you very much! Can I contact you if I have problems writing a code in python? thanx again!!!